# Making Jquery CSS Toggles easier

Tags: jquery, html, css, switch-statement, toggle

I will be using the below snippet of code, for 12 different buttons, to toggle hide og show 12 different divs.

```
$("#klik_multimedia").click(function(){

    $(".datamatiker").css("display","none");
    $(".itdiplom").css("display","none");               
    $(".multimediedesigner").css("display","inline-block");                 
    $(".sprogligstudent").css("display","none");
});
```

As you might imagine, copying and mainting 12 different .click events, and writing the corresponding 12 lines of css "toggles" is rather clumsy.

How I would go about programming it easier?

I am thinking in the lines of

Step A) Initially hide all divs
Step B) Using switch to compare with the clicked element (if possible) and set the corresponding DIV to inline-block

Would that be a good way to go?

EDIT: Codepen http://codepen.io/Ktraving/pen/KaWQbo

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: Currently working on this solution/answer, but am getting an "unpexted identified on each case statement".

```
        $(".klik").click(function(){    // Vent på der bliver klikket på et element med klassen .klik

            $("#oppehoejre").children().css("display","none"); // Skjul alle inderrammer i oppehoejre
            $("#nedrevenstre").children().css("display","none"); // SKjul alle inderammer i nedrevenstre 

            var emne = $(this).attr('id');

            alert(emne);

            switch (emne) {             // Switch til at vises kun det relevante indhold

                Case 'klik_multimedia':
                    $(".multimedia").css("display","inline-block");
                    break;

                Case 'klik_student':
                    $(".sprogligstudent").css("display","inline-block");
                    break;                      

                Case 'klik_datamatiker':
                    $(".datamatiker").css("display","inline-block");                    
                    break;                      

                Case 'klik_itdiplom':
                    $(".itdiplom").css("display","inline-block");                   
                    break;                      

                default:
                    $(".multimedia").css("display","inline-block");
                    break;                      

            };

        });
```

Comment: share the HTML.

Comment: Please put relevant code.

Comment: Heres a pen http://codepen.io/Ktraving/pen/KaWQbo

Answer (score 0):

According to your question i think this is what you are looking for.
This might help you. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/z925tsgn/) is the fiddle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var n = $('button').index(this);
    position = n + 1;
    $("div").removeClass("display_me");
    $("div").addClass("display_none");
    $("div:nth-child(" + position + ")").removeClass("display_none");
    $("div:nth-child(" + position + ")").addClass("display_me");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.display_none {
  display: none;
}

.display_me {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display_none display_me">1</div>
<div class="display_none">2</div>
<div class="display_none">3</div>
<div class="display_none">4</div>
<div class="display_none">5</div>
<div class="display_none">6</div>
<button>
  Click 1
</button>
<button>
  Click 2
</button>
<button>
  Click 3
</button>
<button>
  Click 4
</button>
<button>
  Click 5
</button>
<button>
  Click 6
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this

html:

```
<div id="klik_itdiplom">klik_itdiplom</div>
<div id="klik_student">klik_student</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#klik_student, #klik_itdiplom').on('click', function(){

$(".datamatiker").css("display","none");
    $(".itdiplom").css("display","none");               
    $(".multimediedesigner").css("display","inline-block");                 
    $(".sprogligstudent").css("display","none");

});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s65d0d3z/1/)

Comment: one more way to do this is you can add class on your all divs lets say 'js-klick' and you can just call single function on this class

Comment: Just added an example of what I am trying to do, to the original post. Please kook under EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

The below code will allow me to manage showing/hiding elements a lot easier, than writing .click block for each case.

I can now extend the page with the 8 extra cases, without too many lines of additional code.

```
$(".klik").click(function(){    // Vent på der bliver klikket på et element med klassen .klik

    $("#oppehoejre").children().css("display","none"); // Skjul alle inderrammer i oppehoejre
    $("#nedrevenstre").children().css("display","none"); // SKjul alle inderammer i nedrevenstre 

    var emne = $(this).attr('id');

    // alert(emne); // bruges kun ved debugging

    switch (emne) {             // Switch til at vises kun det relevante indhold

        case 'klik_multimedia':
            $(".multimediedesigner").css("display","inline-block");
            break;
        case 'klik_student':
            $(".sprogligstudent").css("display","inline-block");
            break;                      
        case 'klik_datamatiker':
            $(".datamatiker").css("display","inline-block");                    
            break;                      
        case 'klik_itdiplom':
            $(".itdiplom").css("display","inline-block");                   
            break;                      
        default:
            $(".multimedia").css("display","inline-block");

    };
```